# accessing svn on ubuntu from windows 7 PCS

Tags: windows, svn, ubuntu

I have a svn installation and its repository  on ubuntu system/server but our client PCS have windows 7. Can anyone provide me the good way to access svn on ubuntu from windows 7 PCS.

Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

The OS or architecture of the client and server are irrelevant. There are [a few options](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html) for you, the best and most common would be s[erve the repositories through apache](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache) on your ubuntu box.
The ubuntu docs [on the subject](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion#Access_via_WebDAV_protocol_.28http%3a.2BAC8ALw.29) are good

Answer (score 1):

You can set up SVN with Apache2:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion#Access_via_WebDAV_protocol_.28http%3a.2BAC8ALw.29

But, when using different operating systems, take care about the codification of text files when commit. Ubuntu uses UTF-8.